# iterate over string constants

Tags: matlab

I have predefined set of string constants. For each of them i want to write graphic. So I want to do something like that:

```
stocks = ['MSFT', 'INTC', 'GOOG']; // incorrect in matlab
for stock = stocks
    ...
    figure;
    plotyy(....
    title(stock)
end
```

The question is how to declare such string array and how to iterate over it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
stocks = {'MSFT', 'INTC', 'GOOG'}; 
for stock = stocks
    ...
    figure;
    plotyy(....
    title(stock{1})
end
```

Comment: @javapowered: out of habit. Title works with cell arrays, most other operations don't.

Answer (score 2):

It's called cell in Matlab. Just replace the [] with {}

Also use the curled for accessing.